# HTML 5 Local Storage not working in ie 11 (v 11.0.42) with DOM Storage Enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm attempting to create a program for work, blah blah... Local Storage isn't working correctly in prod ie 11. 
It works fine in Chrome (which I wish everyone would just use) and also works correctly in the ie internal server version in Aptana when i test it.
Here's my code:
jQuery

```
function lsTest(){
    var test = 'test';
    try {
          localStorage.setItem(test, test);
          localStorage.removeItem(test);
          return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testbutton").click(function(){
                  var test = 'test';


        if(lsTest() === true){
            $("body").css("background", "blue"); 
            $("#test").html(" its here! ");
        }else{
            $("#test").html(" its BROKE! ");
        }


    });
});

            $(document).ready(function() { 

                hideElems();        
                testStorage();
                showSSO();

            });

function hideElems(){
    $(".functionalSelect,#inbound,#outbound").hide();
}

function selection(select){
functionSelect = select;

} 

function testStorage(){

    var alice = localStorage.getItem('functionthing');
    if(!localStorage.getItem('functionthing')) {
        populateStorage();
    }
    else if(localStorage.getItem('functionthing') == "OB"){ 
             $("#outbound").show();
             $(".success").html("You have selected Outbound");
             $("body").css("background", "grey");   
         }
         else if(localStorage.getItem('functionthing') == "IB"){  
                 $("#inbound").show();
                 $(".success").html("This means " + alice);
                 $("body").css("background", "#add8e6");
        }
    } 

    function populateStorage(){
        var divSet = '<div class="functionalSelect"> <p>Select your function </p>';
        var buttons = "<button onClick=selection('OB') class='Out'>Outbound</button> <span> </span><button onClick=selection('IB') class='In'>Inbound</button>";
        var end = "</div>";
        $(".selector").html(divSet + buttons + end);

    }

    //==============================================
    //Documenation functions 
    //=============================================     

    function documentationEntry(){
        var Label1 = '<label>SSO: </label><input type="text" id="SSO">';
        var Label2 = '<label> Dept: </label><input type="text" value = "frd" id="dept" readonly>';
        var select1 = '<span> </span><label>Site: </label><select id = "site"><option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>';
        var select2 = '<option value="can">Canton</option><option value="chl">Charlotte</option><option value="hyd">Hyderabad</option><option value="ket">Kettering</option><option value="man">Manila</option><option value="phx">Phoenix</option></select>';
        var selectButton = '<br /><br /><button id="sendInfo">Lock Info</button>';
        select1 += select2;



        $(".entryHeader").html(Label1 + Label2 + select1 + selectButton);

    }


    function showSSO(){
        var caterpiller = localStorage.getItem('SingleSignOn');
        var marchhare = localStorage.getItem('department');
        var queenofHearts = localStorage.getItem('entered_site');   

        if(!localStorage.getItem('SingleSignOn')) {
        documentationEntry();
        }else{
        $('.entryHeader').hide();


        $(".report").html(marchhare + "/" + queenofHearts + "/ ib/ stuff" + caterpiller);
        }

    }


        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#sendInfo").click(function(){
                var SSO_Entry = $('#SSO').val();
                var entered_site = $('#site :selected').val();
                var dept = 'frd';

                if(!SSO_Entry || site == ""){

                    $(".report").html("Your Entry is incomplete");
                    $(".report").css("color", "red");
                }else{  
                        localStorage.setItem('department', dept);       
                        localStorage.setItem('entered_site', entered_site); 
                        localStorage.setItem('SingleSignOn', SSO_Entry);    
                        showSSO();  
                        $(".entryHeader").hide();
                        $(".report").html("");
                    }


                });
            });


    //===========================================
    //End documentaion functions 
    //===========================================       
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".functionalSelect").click(function(){


            if(functionSelect == "OB"){
                localStorage.setItem('functionthing', functionSelect);  
                        $(".success").html("your selection is Outbound");   
                         $("body").css("background", "grey");
                        }else if(functionSelect == "IB"){
                                  localStorage.setItem('functionthing', functionSelect);    
                                  $(".success").html("your selection is Inbound");  
                                  $("body").css("background", "#add8e6");       

                            }

                        $(".selector").hide();
                    });
                });

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".clearit").click(function(){
                        localStorage.clear();
                        location.reload();
                    });
                });
```

CSS

```
#entryWrapper{
    width:600px;
    padding:5px;
    border:solid 1px black;
}
.clearit{
    float:right;

}

.success{
    height:50px;

}
.entryHeader{
    width:475px;
    height:75px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
}


.entryHeader input{
    width:100px;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Unicorn</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" 
  charset="UTF-8"/>


  <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
 <script>
 </script>
 <style>
 </style>

</head>
<body>
  <section id="entryWrapper">

  <button class="clearit">clear</button>    
  <section class="entryHeader"></section>

    <section class="report"></section>

  <section class = "selector"></section>

  <div id="inbound"> this right here is inbound</div>
  <div id="outbound">and this, kind sir, is outbound</div>


  <div class ="success"><p>Your selection will be shown here</p></div>
  </section>

  <div id="test"></div>
  <button id="testbutton">test me!</button>  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I do not see a question here.

Comment: What exactly isn't work correctly about it? Are you getting errors on the console about using it? Is it getting set to something its not supposed to, etc. Explain more, and leave out code that is irrelevant (like css as that doesnt affect localStorage).

Comment: @lordrhodos... sorry... to phrase as a question... could you please help me make my page work correctly in ie?

Comment: @PatrickEvans - None of the items associated with the local storage functions are loading correctly.

Comment: I guess most importantly, using the local storage test function is showing that local storage isn't setting a variable.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. 
ie won't accept localStorage when a page is local, it has to be via a server location. 
I uploaded the page to a server and it works fine. 
Strange that Chrome will let you test local. 
Also explains why it worked correctly in Aptana.